# Godot apk export error [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES: Failed collecting certificates for /data/app/vmdl1039923179.tmp/base.apk

Tags: android, apk, game-engine, godot

I am trying to install the apk generated from godot in mobile but installation fails. When tried to install the apk from godot via usb it is showing me error

```
Project export for platform: Android - Failed.

[Run): Could not install to device: adb: failed to install C/**/AppData/Local/Godot/tmpexport.1682661593.apk: Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES: Failed collecting certificates for /data/app/vmdl1039923179.tmp/base.apk Failed to collect certificates from /data/app/vmdl1039923179.tmp/base.apk Attempt to get length of null array]

Performing Streamed Install
```

Not able to install the generated apk. The debugged and release one also.

I am using **godot version 3.5.2 in windows 10 machine**

Please help me to resolve this possible.
Same screen shot attaching here. [image]

Comment: It's a known problem and not solved yet in version 3.5.x, however it should already be fixed in version 4. It can have multiple reasons. Possibly it uses the wrong build tool for the target version. To try a quick fix, you could copy the folder with the build tool for your target version and then rename it to something that comes in first position in lexical order. take a look here:
https://github.com/godotengine/godot/issues/58192#issuecomment-1042358751